# Changing each list type element of a dataframe to second element of the list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe with elements of list type in it. Now I want to use pandas or numpy to replace
each element(each list) of this dataframe to second element of this element(list). How can I do that?
I wrote the below code to make a trial dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,7],[0,5]],'b':[[3,1],[4,0]],'c':[[1,4],[2,0]]})
```

My df looks like:

```
    a     b     c
0 [1,7] [3,1] [1,4]
1 [0,5] [4,0] [2,0]
```

Now  I want df to be changed like shown below:

```
  a b c
0 7 1 4
1 5 0 0
```

I tried using replace function, lambda function etc but nothing worked.

I don't want to use loops or anything that takes time to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it, using [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html?highlight=applymap#pandas.DataFrame.applymap)

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x[1])
```

```
    a   b   c
0   7   1   4
1   5   0   0
```